# Python regex find all substrings between two character pairs

Tags: python, regex

I have tried previous answers here on SO. I was able to find only one subset of several.

here is the code and sample that I am working on.

```
s = "{| mySting0 |}  The {| mySting1 |}  The {| mySting2 |}  The {| mySting3 |}  make it work "

result = re.findall('{\|(.*)|}', s)
```

the output is,

```
[' mySting0 |}  The {| mySting1 |}  The {| mySting2 |}  The {| mySting3 |}  make it work ']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*What am I doing wrong?*" - using a greedy regex, not escaping the second pipe character with a backslash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
>>> s = "{| mySting0 |}  The {| mySting1 |}  The {| mySting2 |}  The {| mySting3 |}  make it work "
>>> re.findall(r'{\|(.*?)\|}', s)
[' mySting0 ', ' mySting1 ', ' mySting2 ', ' mySting3 ']
```

**Changes are:**

1. Use lazy quantifier `.*?` instead of greedy `.*`
2. Excape 2nd `|` as well in your regex